# Add no fields to the tx_news model from another ext

Tags: model-view-controller, typo3, typo3-6.1.x, tt-news

I used this to extend tx_news: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/latest/Main/Tutorial/ExtendingNews/Index.html

So I created a `Class/Domain/Model/News.php` and a `Ressources/Private/extend-news.txt`. And I also find the file `typo3temp/Cache/Code/cache_phpcode/Domain_Model_News.php` with my content in it:

```
/***********************************************************************
    this is partial from: /var/www/vhosts/xx.ch/development/typo3conf/ext/template_xx/Classes/Domain/Model/News.php
***********************************************************************/
/**
 * @var int
 */
protected $txSogexpandnewsHoehe;


/**
 * Get Hoehe
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getTxSogexpandnewsHoehe() {
    return $this->txSogexpandnewsHoehe;
}
```

The field is in the database, added with ext_tables.sql

```
CREATE TABLE tx_news_domain_model_news (
    tx_sogexpandnews_favorit boolean
    tx_sogexpandnews_hoehe int
);
```

The field has the value "2" in the database, but I dont get any value and a vardump returns NULL

```
var_dump($news->getTxSogexpandnewsHoehe());
```

What do I miss?

Comment: The manual you linked to is for the extension `news`, not `tt_news`. Maybe that is the reason it does not work?

Comment: My mistake. i wanted to write tx_news not tt_news. I use the new news extension